# create a new table with caculated field, with data from two different tables

Tags: r

I have to data tables:

The first table shows mentors' names and all the students assigned to each one of them.

```
    mentor          student_name
    Dr. Brown       Michael
    Dr. Brown       Diana
    Dr. Brown       Peter
    Dr. Brown       Christopher
    Dr. Brown       Stacy
    Ms. Lindblom    Rose
    Ms. Lindblom    Anne
    Ms. Lindblom    Steven
    Ms. Lindblom    Gloria
    Mr. Apple       Juan
    Mr. Apple       Francis
    Mr. Apple       David
    Mr. Apple       Sonja
    Mr. Apple       Dakota
    Mr. Apple       Latoya
    Mr. Apple       Avril
    Mr. Apple       James
    Mr. Apple       Stewart
    Mr. Apple       Sophia
```

The second table shows one-on-one mentoring sessions between mentors and their students

```
 mentor         date_of_tutoring    student_name
 Dr. Brown      07/14/2019          Peter
 Dr. Brown      07/15/2019          Christopher
 Ms. Lindblom   06/28/2019          Gloria
 Mr. Apple      06/20/2019          Sophia
 Mr. Apple      06/22/2019          Latoya
 Mr. Apple      06/25/2019          Juan
 Mr. Apple      06/26/2019          Avril
```

Each mentor needs to hold one mentoring session with each student during the school year.

I want to create a new table that shows the percent of the mentoring task completed. Each mentor will have completed the task (100%) when they have had one-on-one mentoring sessions with all the students assigned to them.

For instance, based on table 2 data, and the number of students assigned to each mentor, I would like to create a new table like this:

```
 teacher           %_mentoring_completed
 Dr. Brown          40%
 Ms. Lindblom       25%
 Mr. Apple          40%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `table` to count frequencies of `mentor`, assuming all the unique mentors are present in both the dataframes.

```
stack(table(df2$mentor)/table(df1$mentor))

#  values          ind
#1   0.40    Dr. Brown
#2   0.40    Mr. Apple
#3   0.25 Ms. Lindblom
```

If they are not or if they are not in same order a safer option is to use `factor` with `levels` specified individually to get output in correct order

```
stack(table(factor(df2$mentor, levels = unique(df1$mentor)))/
      table(factor(df1$mentor, levels = unique(df1$mentor))))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be do a join with the two datasets, grouped by 'mentor', get the `mean` of non-NA logical vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
left_join(df1, df2) %>% 
   group_by(mentor) %>% 
    summarise(PercentageMentoringCompleted = str_c(100 * 
             mean(!is.na(date_of_tutoring)), "%"))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  mentor       PercentageMentoringCompleted
#  <chr>        <chr>                       
#1 Dr. Brown    40%                         
#2 Mr. Apple    40%                         
#3 Ms. Lindblom 25%
```

---

or another option is to use `count`

```
library(purrr)
list(df2, df1) %>% map(~ .x %>% 
           dplyr::count(mentor)) %>% 
           reduce(inner_join, by = 'mentor') %>%
           transmute(mentor, perc = 100 * n.x/n.y)
```

---

Or with `base R` using `merge` and `aggregate`

```
aggregate(PercentageMentoringCompleted ~ mentor,
  transform(merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE), 
       PercentageMentoringCompleted = !is.na(date_of_tutoring)), mean)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(mentor = c("Dr. Brown", "Dr. Brown", "Dr. Brown", 
"Dr. Brown", "Dr. Brown", "Ms. Lindblom", "Ms. Lindblom", "Ms. Lindblom", 
"Ms. Lindblom", "Mr. Apple", "Mr. Apple", "Mr. Apple", "Mr. Apple", 
"Mr. Apple", "Mr. Apple", "Mr. Apple", "Mr. Apple", "Mr. Apple", 
"Mr. Apple"), student_name = c("Michael", "Diana", "Peter", "Christopher", 
"Stacy", "Rose", "Anne", "Steven", "Gloria", "Juan", "Francis", 
"David", "Sonja", "Dakota", "Latoya", "Avril", "James", "Stewart", 
"Sophia")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))

df2 <- structure(list(mentor = c("Dr. Brown", "Dr. Brown", "Ms. Lindblom", 
"Mr. Apple", "Mr. Apple", "Mr. Apple", "Mr. Apple"), 
 date_of_tutoring = c("07/14/2019", 
"07/15/2019", "06/28/2019", "06/20/2019", "06/22/2019", "06/25/2019", 
"06/26/2019"), student_name = c("Peter", "Christopher", "Gloria", 
"Sophia", "Latoya", "Juan", "Avril")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```